# How do I install the Glasgow Haskell Compiler?

Tags: 10.10, installation, haskell

How can I install `ghc` in Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ghc6 is in the repositories. Just install it from the Ubuntu Software Center, or by clicking on the link below:

## [ghc6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ghc6) [image: Install ghc6]

Answer (score 2):

In terminal enter the following,

```
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

It will install all the tools needed to develop haskell..

Comment: I get this error when I try to use apt-get; E: Couldn't find package haskell-platform

Answer (score 0):

Typing in the terminal `sudo apt-get install ghc6` works as well..